# Tracking in Mobile Analytics system

Tags: iphone, android, logging, mobile, analytics

I am developing mobile application for android and for iphone. I have an advanced handmade logger which tracks every user action and sends logs to server. If there is no internet it stores logs and sends them later. 
The questions are is there a logging system on the market, with which I can track anything I want(method logger.write I assume :))
And the main question: which system I should use for complex data analysis? F.ex. to see how much time users with specific phone model spent on given page after visiting another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your main question I suggest you to use [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html). I am using it on Android and it is very simple to integrate. Everything you need to know is on their [WikiPage](http://wiki.flurry.com/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: Nice one. I was using google analytics. This one is worth giving a try.

Answer (score 1):

Both Android and iOS support Google Analytics. It allows you to define your own custom events and offers a lot out-of-the-box for analyses.

Android: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/firebase/android

iOS: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3

Answer (score 1):

There is [Omniture](http://www.omniture.com/en/products/online_analytics/sitecatalyst) for android iphone web.

Comment: The API provided for iPhone is confusing. I've been struggling with a client to get this whole thing to work for weeks now. Definitely not recommended. Flurry and Google Analytics are way easier, though admittedly you can't run it on your own server, so you can't shield your data from Flurry or Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sitecatalyst which is available for all the platforms.
[Check this link](http://www.adobe.com/in/solutions/digital-analytics/marketing-reports-analytics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another good option would be Parse.com, they are evolving every day. I think the best analytics provider would be Omniture (an Adobe service - Paid) followed by Google Analytics (Free).